# How to link individual image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="test_A.png"><img src="test_a_logo.png"  alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" /></a>
    <a href="test_B.png"><img src="test_b_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title=""  /></a>
    <a href="test_C.png"><img src="test_c_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" /></a>
</div>
```

With the code above, if I wanted to give each href=".png" a clickable link how one should make a code?

I tried using wrap() function such as this.

```
$("img").each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.wrap('<a href="test.com" "class="test"></a>');
});
```

It will take me to the test.com but all of the picture takes me to the same site, how can I make it individual so that each img can go to their own site?

Comment: href="test_A.png" to A.com href="test_b.png" to B.com and so on.

Comment: Thank you every one, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/85Ydt/

Add `target` tag with your separate page name to your image. Then, get this target link and wrap each link with jquery.

## HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <img target="test1.html" src="test_a_logo.png"  alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" />   
    <img target="test2.html" src="test_b_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title=""  />    
    <img target="test3.html" src="test_c_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" />    
</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each( function() {
        $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('target')+'" "class="test"></a>');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have this HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="test_a_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" />
    <img src="test_b_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" />
    <img src="test_c_logo.png" alt="" width="469" height="87" class="thumb" title="" />
</div>
```

Using the following JS will append each site in the array to the corresponding image index
      (position in `.test` starting at `0`)

```
var arr_sites = ['test1.com', 'test2.com', 'test3.com']

$(".test img").each(function (indx) {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+arr_sites[indx]+'" "class="test"></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/wXL6C/1/

you wanted these "href="test_A.png" to A.com href="test_b.png" to B.com and so on"

so here is the working code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each( function() {
      $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src').substring(5,6).toUpperCase()+'.com" >  </a>');
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the format `string_url_string`, you can use `split()` to get the `url`:

```
$('img').map(function() {
    var url = this.src.split('_')[1];
    $(this).wrap('<a href="http://www.' + url + '.com">');
});
```

This assumes all your links are prefixed `www` and end with `.com` (which may not always be the case).

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7DR5/2/)

A better approach would to be use [HTML5's data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) - and just store the URL in there:

```
<img src="test_a_logo.png" data-url="http:/www.a.com/" ... />
```

Then just wrap again, and use the `data-url`:

```
$('img').map(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.wrap('<a href="' + $this.data('url') + '">');
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7DR5/3/)